# windows 8 datatemplate population issue

Tags: c#, xaml

I have

```
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

---------template controls
<Image 
                                    x:Name="Name"
                        Source="{Binding Photo.FileName}"

</Image>

            </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                </DataTemplate>
```

The porblem is that i files are in `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`
and when i need to replace source of this Image by whole file path(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder + Photo.FileName).

I Tried to handle Loaded event of an Image, but it did not work.
How can i solve this issue.

Comment: Can you please provide what "did not work" and what you have tried? Also, What errors are you getting?

Comment: Can not figuire out how to handle population event in DataTemplate.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17502.finding-element-in-itemscontrol-datatemplate-listviewgridviewflipview-window-store-apps.aspx  but ContainerFromItem method always return null.